# Query a table so that data in one column could be shown as different fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, pivot, pentaho-report-designer

I have a table that stores data of customer care . The table/view has the following structure.

```
    userid  calls_received    calls_answered    calls_rejected   call_date  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------  
    1030        134              100              34             28-05-2018  
    1012        140              120              20             28-05-2018  
    1045        120              80               40             28-05-2018  
    1030        99               39               50              28-04-2018  
    1045        50               30               20             28-04-2018  
    1045        200              100              100            28-05-2017  
    1030        160               90              70             28-04-2017  
    1045        50               30               20             28-04-2017
```

This is the sample data. The data is stored on day basis.
I have to create a report in a report designer software that takes date as an input. When user selects a date for eg. 28/05/2018. This date is send as parameter  ${call_date}. i have to query the view in such a way that result  should look like as below. If user selects date 28/05/2018 then data of 28/04/2018 and 28/05/2017 should be displayed side by side as like the below column order.

```
    userid | cl_cur | ans_cur | rej_cur |success_percentage |diff_percent|position_last_month| cl_last_mon | ans_las_mon | rej_last_mon |percentage_lm|cl_last_year | ans_last_year | rej_last_year
    1030   | 134    |  100    |  34     |      74.6 %       |  14%       |   2               |      99     |   39        |      50      |  39.3%      | 160         |  90           |  70   
    1045   | 120    |  80     |  40     |      66.6%        |  26.7%     |     1             |      50     |   30        |      20      |   60%       | 50          |  30           |  20
```

The objective of this query is to show data of selected day, data of same day previous month and same day previous years in columns so that user can have a look and compare.  Here the result is ordered by percentage(ans_cur/cl_cur) of   selected day in descending order of calculated percentage and show under  success_percentage.
The column position_last_month is the position of that particular employee in previous month when it is ordered in descending order of percentage. In this example userid 1030 was in 2nd position last month and userid 1045 in 1 st position last month. Similarly I have  to calculate this also for year.
Also there is a field called diff_percent which calculates the difference of percentage between the person who where in same position last month.Same i have to do for last year. How i can achieve this result.Please help.

Comment: Your google search string is "sql server pivot query".

Answer (score 1):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

One method is a `join`:

```
select t.user_id, 
       t.calls_received as cr_cur, t.calls_answered as ca_cur, t.calls_rejected as cr_cur,
       tm.calls_received as cr_last_mon, tm.calls_answered as ca_last_mon, tm.calls_rejected as cr_last_mon,
       ty.calls_received as cr_last_year, ty.calls_answered as ca_last_year, ty.calls_rejected as cr_last_year
from t left join
     t tm
     on tm.userid = t.userid and
        tm.call_date = dateadd(month, -1, t.call_date) left join
     t ty
     on ty.userid = t.userid and
        tm.call_date = dateadd(year, -1, t.call_date)
where t.call_date = ${call_date};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. That really worked for me. But i have got more requirements. I have edited the question. Could you please help.